# Proving an inequality involving a strictly convex function

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Given, $f$ is a **strictly convex** function.

Based on **what assumptions** on '$x$' and '$y$', can I say that the following inequality stands true :

$$f(x) \; + f(y) \; > \; f(x + y) \; \; ?$$

Comment: I think you'll need something more definite than just "convex" for this to hold.  The constant function $f\equiv -1$ is convex but this inequality never holds for any $x.y$.

Comment: How is the constant function $f \equiv -1$ a convex function, sir ?

Comment: Sorry, sir.. I have edited my question.... my assumption is that $f$ is a strictly convex function !

Comment: And I have understood your point that a constant function is a convex function !

Comment: Gerw's answer shows that it will be unreasonable to characterize all pairs $x,y$, but there may still be some way to justify this inequality for sufficiently "large" $x,y$.  None of the examples so far seems to contradict this possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a neat characterization of all $x$ and $y$ satisfying this inequality.

Think of the easy case $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
Then, you want to have
$$x^2 + y^2 > (x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2 \, x \, y + y^2.$$
This holds iff $x \, y < 0$.This set is neither closed nor convex.

Comment: Do you mean "connected" rather than "closed"?  I wouldn't generically expect the solution set of a strict inequality to be closed.

Comment: @ErickWong: Indeed, one cannot expect that this is closed!